# installed lxml but still report not installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, homebrew, lxml

I've installed `lxml` by using command `pip3 install lxml`. However when I run my program, it still reports `lxml not found, please install it`. I don't know why and how to resolve it.

Here is my command and outputs:
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the error coming from `pandas`

`/opt/homebrew/lib/pyhton3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/html.py`

try reinstalling `pandas` or both.

`pip3 uninstall pandas`

`pip3 install pandas`

`pip3 uninstall lxml`

`pip3 install lxml`

Or restart the system or the `jupyter instance`/`notebook` in this case `vs code`